# Is there a way to detect whether Mono uses Boehm GC or SGen GC at runtime?

Tags: mono, xamarin.ios

I'd like to be able detect at runtime whether the Mono runtime uses the Boehm GC or the SGen GC.  I tried googling for solutions and have spent some time browsing Mono documentation, but couldn't find a solution.  Is there a way to detect which GC implementation is used by Mono at runtime?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the GC.MaxGeneration property, it will be 0 when the Boehm GC is used and > 0 with sgen.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the GC implementation being executed you might also want to know if the NewRefCount (NRC) extensions are enabled (or not) on the GC.

You can access that information from:

```
bool NSObject.IsNewRefcountEnabled ();
```

E.g. in [Touch.Unit](https://github.com/spouliot/Touch.Unit/blob/master/NUnitLite/TouchRunner/TouchRunner.cs#L288) runner you'll see:

```
        Writer.WriteLine ("[GC:\t{0}{1}]", GC.MaxGeneration == 0 ? "Boehm": "sgen", 
            NSObject.IsNewRefcountEnabled () ? "+NewRefCount" : String.Empty);
```

so that the test results logs include the GC information and options.